# Cannot convert the "/Action:" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I am getting this error while trying to execute below power-shell (7.0) script.
This script updates all the databases using a dacpac file and SqlPackage.exe.

```
[string]$SqlPackagePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\SqlPackage.exe"
[int]$ErrorCount = 0
$DatabaseNames | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    
    echo "$_ - Updating database using DACPAC."
    
    dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio*" -Filter "SqlPackage.exe" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{$_.FullName} {$using:SqlPackagePath /Action:Publish /tu:$using:DatabaseUsername /tp:$using:DatabasePassword /tsn:$using:ServerInstance /tdn:"$_" /sf:using:$DacpacLocation /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False}
        
  }
```

I am new to powershell script. It looks like the issue seems to be with the way arguments are being passed so I just put {} around arguments as I was getting another below error for $using:SqlPackagePath parameter but this doesn't seem to be working

Cannot convert the "somepath" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here - is `$SqlPackagePath` the name of an executable you're trying to execute? And the full path to `SqlPackage.exe` is one of the arguments?

Comment: Yes, with 'dir' command this script looks for the SqlPackage .exe within the specified path if does not find then the full path of the SqlPackage.exe is passed throught $SqlPackagePath variable. Then using that exe it tires to update all the databases using dacpac file in for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "escape" arguments by nesting them in script block literals.

It sounds like you want to do:

```
[string]$SqlPackagePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\SqlPackage.exe"
[int]$ErrorCount = 0
$DatabaseNames | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    
    echo "$_ - Updating database using DACPAC."

    # locate SqlPackage, otherwise default to `$SqlPackagePath` from calling scope
    $sqlPackageExe = dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio*" -Filter "SqlPackage.exe" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Select -First 1
    if(-not $sqlPackageExe){
        $sqlPackageExe = $using:SqlPackagePath
    }

    # use the `&` invocation operator to execute SqlPackage
    & $sqlPackageExe /Action:Publish /tu:$using:DatabaseUsername /tp:$using:DatabasePassword /tsn:$using:ServerInstance /tdn:"$_" /sf:$using:DacpacLocation /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False        
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but now getting this error -> out-lineoutput: The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by a user-specified "format-list" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.

Comment: Did you use any `Format-*` commands (or `ft` or `fl`) for any of the variables that you're referencing with `$using:`?

Comment: No, this statement causing the issue which returns a table with 3 rows. I need only 1st record i.e. full path of the exe. $sqlPackageExe = dir -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio*" -Filter "SqlPackage.exe" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue. How can i get 1st entry or path?

Comment: Pipe it through `|Select -First 1`, updated the answer